# Parse Query Crashes (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm building an iOS app using Swift and Parse. I have a simple data table with three keys. I'm trying to use a Parse query in `viewDidAppear` to access each element in the table. I'm trying to `println()` the elements for now, and then later would like to append them to a `[String]` array.

Here's what I've tried:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "BCCalendar")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        for object in objects {
            var event = object["events"] as String
            var date = object["dates"] as String
            var formattedDate = object["formattedDates"] as String

            println("Event \(event) is on \(date) which is formatted as \(formattedDate)")
        }
    } else {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Every time I run the code, the app crashes with the error: `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1008564b0)`. I've tried multiple methods to query from Parse. I've made sure the table has elements in it. But, I still have the same problem. Any ideas? Thanks!

**More details on the crash:** It crashes on this line: `var event = object["events"] as String`. I've added a breakpoint and it does reach the for loop. The object does contain the right elements (I was able to print it somehow before).

Comment: What line does it crash on? Do you have more details for the error? Do you have an exception breakpoint turned on? Have you tried putting in a breakpoint and checking whether it reaches the block / whether the object contains what you expect it to contain?

Comment: @shim I added more details to my question.

Comment: So the object contains a value for the key "events" ? Is it actually a String?

Comment: @shim It's an array key. I'm trying to access each String element in the array.

Comment: Well you can't cast an array as a String...

Comment: @shim I think my approach to this query is completely incorrect. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You have to do `object["events"] as [String]` if your events is an array of strings

Comment: @ztan Perfect! I got all the elements. How can I make them a String though? Because, they print like this: `[July 1]`

Comment: You want to concatenate all the events in the array into a single string?

Comment: @shim I want to access each event as its own element. The only reason the key is of Array type is because the elements were uploaded in that form. Each element is really a string from an array element.

Comment: @shim Essentially, I'm now trying to append `event` to array `events`, but I can't because [String] isn't convertible to String.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem @shim. Please make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your events is an array of String, so if you want to print the events, you have to do the following:

```
var events = object["events"] as [String]
for event in events {
    println(event)
}
```